# Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{r-1} \sqrt{\frac{2}{π}}e^{\frac{-(log x)^2}{2}}dx=e^{\frac{r^2}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm supposed to show that$$\
\sqrt{\frac{2}{π}}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{r-1} e^{\frac{-(\log x)^2}{2}}dx=e^{\frac{r^2}{2}}$$ then $r\in \mathbb{N}$

I tried substituting $\log x = y$ without any success and I'm pretty stuck at the moment. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: your substitution should lead you to a straightforward gaussian integral..

Comment: The integral is actually $\color{#C00}{2}\,e^{\frac{r^2}2}$.

Comment: Use Ramanujan’s Master Theorem ie write the non-kernel integrand as an infinite series in x ie Mclaurin series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=\log x$ works. After that you just get:

$$2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}+ry}dy$$

then you complete the square and you write it again an integral of a gaussian pdf.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, how do you go from $x^{r-1}$ to $e^{rx}$? like did you forgot to switch from dx to dy or am I just completely lost?

Comment: Yes, it should be y instead of x. $y=\log x$ so $x=e^y$ so $dx=e^y dy$ so $x^{r-1} dx$ becomes $e^{y(r-1)}e^y dy = e^{ry} dy$. Corrected.

Comment: And then I take out $e^{\frac{r^2}{2}}$ from the integral how am I supposed to know that what I have left is a pdf? Nevermind I understand now, thank you for the help.

Comment: By completing the square. $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}+ry}=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{y^2-2ry+r^2}{2}}e^\frac{r^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{(y-r)^2}{2}}e^\frac{r^2}{2}$ After you take out $e^\frac{r^2}{2}$, the rest is the pdf of a Gaussian random variable with mean $r$ and variance 1.

Comment: The integral after the substitution should be from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. The integral is actually double what is stated in the question.

Comment: Yeah... corrected

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty x^{r-1} e^{-\frac{\log(x)^2}2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{rx} e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\,e^{\frac{r^2}2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=2\,e^{\frac{r^2}2}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto e^x$
$(2)$: substitute $x\mapsto x+r$
$(3)$: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{2\pi}$

Comment: the only  useful answer (+1)

Comment: No idea why you were downvoted, I upvoted you.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=\ln x$
$$dt= \frac{dx}{x}$$
Substituting in the equation
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}}\int x^{r-1} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dx$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}}\int x^{r} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} \frac{dx}{x} $$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}}\int e^{tr} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}}\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t^2-2rt)} dt$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}}\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}((t-r)^2-r^2)} dt$$
$$e^{\frac{r^2}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}\int e^{-\frac{1}{2} (t-r)^2} dt$$
Substitute $a=t-r$ so $a=\ln x -r$
$$e^{\frac{r^2}{2} }\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}}\int e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} da$$

> further you can follow
>   http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+e%5E-(x%5E2%2F2)+from+0+to+infinity

$$e^{\frac{r^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}}\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}$$
$$e^{\frac{r^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Then you substitute I don't understand how $x^{r-1}$ disappear

Comment: Because the limits of integration were not tracked, this answer is half the actual integral.